# Как через gstreamer можно реализовать трансляцию медиафайла в localhost на python?

Tags: python, flask, gstreamer

Подскажите, как сделать трансляцию готового медиафайла (.mp4) через **gstreamer** в localhost и связать это как-то с html тегом . Бэкенд пишу на **flask.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Готовый mp4 можно отдать статикой, если кодек поддерживается браузером. Если кодек не поддерживается, то конвертнуть его в h264+aac.